# How to check the voucher is valid in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I want to create a CMS page in my shop where client could check his voucher. In /classes/CartRule.php I found `checkValidity()` function. It's look good because this function return "This voucher is disabled" - for example. How to use this function ? I want to add input field where user past his voucher and then check him.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all create an input field to enter coupon. Google it and you will find many results. After input field is created and once you submitted the coupon to any controller, use below code to check status of coupon.

Lets say `getStatusOfCoupon()` is a function to call after coupon is submitted.

```
public function getStatusOfCoupon($coupon){
    $id=$this->getIdByCode($coupon);
    $obj = new CartRuleCore($id);
    $context = Context::getContext();
    $response=$obj->checkValidity($context);
    d($response);// do whatever you want of this response.        
}

public static function getIdByCode($code)
{
    if (!Validate::isCleanHtml($code)) {
        return false;
    }
    return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue('SELECT `id_cart_rule` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule` WHERE `code` = \''.pSQL($code).'\'');
}
```

Comment: I create input field in cms. Like this: jsfiddle.net/3gk0uohj/2 and then in \override\controllers\front\CmsController.php paste Your code (class CmsController extends CmsControllerCore). The d($response); change to echo $response; This is correctly ? Thanks for help.

Comment: You have to submit this form so that input value comes to php value and then call `getStatusOfCoupon()` and send coupon in it as a paramter

Comment: That I understand but I don't know how. What should be in <form action=""> ? In php it's easy bcs in action form I have script with getStatusOfCoupon() which wait for params. In Prestashop I don't know no how to call this function. I google it but Can't find result with system prestashop. Kind regards

Comment: In the action, path of CmsController should be there so that value of coupon gets submitted to CmsController and you can use my code in controller for working.

Now the question is how to submit values to CmsController. Please google it and you will find many answers or take an example of subscribe field

Comment: It's possible to get complete solution ? I can not find any similar task in Google. Thanks